# JSDoc: Narrow type without creating a new variable

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns `string | symbol` and a narrow function that will exit the process if the type is `symbol`, thereby narrowing the type:

```js
// string | symbol
const foo = myFunc();

if (narrow(foo)) {
    process.exit(0);
}

// string
const bar = foo;
```

However, creating new values just to get correctly narrowed types is rather silly. TS is perfectly aware that `foo`, at that point, is a string, so why would (say) `foo.toUpperCase()` be an error? The type is no longer `string | symbol`.

How can I get `foo` reporting the correct type **without** creating new values?

Comment: `as` keyword can be used like `const bar = foo as string`

Comment: @Navitas28 That solves nothing? `const bar = foo` already works, but as the text indicates, I don't want to create wasteful intermediaries and I'm not authoring in TypeScript.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your problem...? It works for me: https://tsplay.dev/w29eVW

Comment: If this was wrapped in a function, it would work as you expect. But using `process.exit` might not be properly handled as a return.

Comment: @zenly Weird, your reproduction is totally correct. It seems to be an issue with editor then that I'll have to track down.

Comment: A few reloads of my editor and I'm struggling to reliably reproduce. It seems like it's a tsserver bug that might be tied to using a local version of TypeScript instead of the included one? Good to know it's not a usage error at least.